# Calculate elapsed time and cpu time of a parallel program

Tags: java, c++, c, parallel-processing

All:

I have a parallel program which has three processes. Each process is running on a different machine. I would like to calculate the elapsed time and CPU time of the parallel program. Is the following formula correct?

Elapsed time = the maximum elapsed time of three processes

CPU time = the sum of each process's CPU time

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the processes start at the same time.